# How to set up multiple site with different domain / ports in umbraco

Tags: iis-7, umbraco, umbraco6, umbraco7

I am trying to setup umbraco site to point to multiple domain / port (css change / Template for each domain )

I have gone through many blog and followed the following steps , but I am not able to archived for above mention case. (I am using umbraco 4.7.0)

--> Have created two Document Type and respective Template as shown in image.

1) DTypeOne

2) DTypeTwo

[image]

And thereby created Content
1)  Name > SiteCountOne  , Document Type > DTypeOne , Template > DtypeOne

2)  Name > SiteCountTwo  , Document Type > DTypeTwo , Template > DtypeTwo

And have added two different port from IIS Site Binding to this umbraco site. (9083 ,9084) , And have set Manage hostname > localhost:9084

[image]

But when I try to call access site from typing URL http :// localhost:9084' it renders contain of " DtypeOne ". And not the contains of Template DtypeTwo

So for render for contains of DtypeOne when Call is made from port :9083 and render contains of DtypeTwo when call in made from port :9084. 
do I need to do any more setting or I have missed any step .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is the use of ports. Older versions of Umbraco were a bit flaky using a port  as part of the domain. If you use a host name instead, that should work fine. As you're working on localhost, you could set up a hosts file entry for this for something like site1.local and site2.local, and have your umbraco site pick those up instead.

I believe it is possible to specify ports on newer versions of Umbraco, starting with when the pipeline was rewritten. If you used a more up to date version (at least version 6), you should be able to use ports in the manner you want to without issues.